# Put data class with annotations into Amazon DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, annotations

I need to put my data classes into **DynamoDb**. How can I make it with annotations?

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Item(
    @DynamoDBAttribute var name: String = "",
    @DynamoDBAttribute var id: String = "",
    @DynamoDBAttribute var stuff: String = ""
    ...
)

suspend fun putItemInTable() {
        val request = PutItemRequest {
            tableName = "table"
            item = Item() // How to send it properly?
        }

        DynamoDbClient { region = AWS_REGION }.use { ddb ->
            ddb.putItem(request)
            println("A new item was placed into.")
        }
}
```

I suppose, it should be not much harder Android + Room converters out of the box, right?

**build.gradle.kts:**

```
implementation ("aws.sdk.kotlin:dynamodb:$awsVersion")
implementation ("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.12.477")
```

Current AWS documentation is unorganized, how can I get Kotlin version of `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb`?

Comment: What document are you looking at to get that code example. Its not in the Kotlin AWS Docs.

Comment: Tried to combine those: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-items.html
But found Gradle dependencies only somewhere outside.

Comment: As i specified in my answer - look at the Developer Doc for Kotlin and use the SDK for full benefits of Kotlin. DO not use Java V1 with Kotlin.

Comment: Also - find a functioning Gradle build file here - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/services/dynamodb

Comment: I did see that file, no mapping there. Looks like it is a long way to add it to Kotlin especially if all aws.sdk.kotlin versions in beta.

Comment: If you need to use Mapping over Kotlin and Coroutine functionality -- still move away from Java V1 and move to the AWS SDK for Java V2 and the Enhanced Client. Still a better choice then V1.  See -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html

Comment: Thanks. Maybe using Kotlin version is still better as for now, especially with Android. But if this V2 supports both mapping and coroutines - not sure why it's not implemented in Kotlin version.

Comment: I think the SDK team is aware.  It still a new SDK - but far better then Java V1. That SDK is not recommended to use any more. If you want to use Java - move to AWS SDK for Java V2,

Comment: See my update about Android

Answer (score 1):

Although you are using this data type that uses v2:

**com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute**

This is actually **AWS SDK for Java V1**. To use Kotlin and DynamoDB, you should consider using the **AWS SDK for Kotlin**, not **AWS SDK for Java V1**.

The Developer Guide for AWS SDK for Kotlin is here:

[What is the AWS SDK for Kotlin?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

The **AWS SDK for Kotlin** supports language features like coroutines that you will not get with Java V1. See:

[Coroutines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/coroutines.html)

You can use the A**WS SDK for Kotlin** to interact with Amazon DynamoDB. There are many examples. I suggest you look in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) under the Kotlin SDK and DynamoDB section:

[DynamoDB examples using SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/kotlin_1_dynamodb_code_examples.html)

You will find many code examples including how to use this SDK - including this multi operation scenario:

[Get started with tables, items, and queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/kotlin_1_dynamodb_code_examples.html#scenarios)

If you prefer - look at AWS Github for DynamoDB:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/services/dynamodb

In Github, you will find how to add an item using the **AWS SDK for Kotlin**. Notice the use of **mutableMapOf** to add an item.

```
  package com.kotlin.dynamodb

  // snippet-start:[dynamodb.kotlin.put_item.import]
  import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient
  import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue
  import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.model.PutItemRequest
  import kotlin.system.exitProcess
  // snippet-end:[dynamodb.kotlin.put_item.import]

  /**
  Before running this Kotlin code example, set up your development 
  environment, including your credentials.

  For more information, see the following documentation topic:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer- 
  guide/setup.html
  */

 suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val usage = """
        Usage:
            <tableName> <key> <keyVal> <albumtitle> <albumtitleval> <awards> <awardsval> <Songtitle> <songtitleval>

        Where:
            tableName - The Amazon DynamoDB table in which an item is placed (for example, Music3).
            key - The key used in the Amazon DynamoDB table (for example, Artist).
            keyval - The key value that represents the item to get (for example, Famous Band).
            albumTitle - The album title (for example, AlbumTitle).
            AlbumTitleValue - The name of the album (for example, Songs About Life).
            Awards - The awards column (for example, Awards).
            AwardVal - The value of the awards (for example, 10).
            SongTitle - The song title (for example, SongTitle).
            SongTitleVal - The value of the song title (for example, Happy Day).
            """"

    if (args.size != 9) {
        println(usage)
        exitProcess(0)
    }

    val tableName = args[0]
    val key = args[1]
    val keyVal = args[2]
    val albumTitle = args[3]
    val albumTitleValue = args[4]
    val awards = args[5]
    val awardVal = args[6]
    val songTitle = args[7]
    val songTitleVal = args[8]

    putItemInTable(tableName, key, keyVal, albumTitle, albumTitleValue, awards, awardVal, songTitle, songTitleVal)
}

  // snippet-start:[dynamodb.kotlin.put_item.main]
  suspend fun putItemInTable(
    tableNameVal: String,
    key: String,
    keyVal: String,
    albumTitle: String,
    albumTitleValue: String,
    awards: String,
    awardVal: String,
    songTitle: String,
    songTitleVal: String
   ) {
   
    val itemValues = mutableMapOf<String, AttributeValue>()

    // Add all content to the table.
    itemValues[key] = AttributeValue.S(keyVal)
    itemValues[songTitle] = AttributeValue.S(songTitleVal)
    itemValues[albumTitle] = AttributeValue.S(albumTitleValue)
    itemValues[awards] = AttributeValue.S(awardVal)

    val request = PutItemRequest {
        tableName = tableNameVal
        item = itemValues
    }

    DynamoDbClient { region = "us-east-1" }.use { ddb ->
        ddb.putItem(request)
        println(" A new item was placed into $tableNameVal.")
    }
   }
  // snippet-end:[dynamodb.kotlin.put_item.main]
```

**ANDROID**

I noticed in your comments you mentioned Android. Find this **Android/AWS SDK for Kotlin** tutorial. It will help you get up and running with the AWS SDK for Kotlin in an Android Studio project.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/usecases/first_android_app

Comment: I found the stuff about coroutines and no mapping there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212036/modelling-complex-types-for-dynamodb-in-kotlin
Looks like it was your answer. Hope something changed with mapping after 1.5 years passed.

Comment: The AWS  SDK for Kotlin for DynamoDB does not yet support data mapping.  You need to use a Kotlin collection (ie --  mutableMapOf) that i showed in my code example to add an item.

Comment: Yeah, it's sad especially if Kotlin can't make a loop through its parameters.

Comment: Although the SDK is new , you should decide if you prefer full support of language features such as corountines that you do not get with Java SDK vs using collections to add items.

Comment: Looks like coroutines is something better for performance.

Comment: That is a correct assumption